# Display image when navbar is collapsed

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap3.  I have a `navbar` with a logo but I only want the logo to appear when the `navbar` is collapsed.  I have too many dropdowns and so the logo does not fit (nor look good) when the `navbar` is not collapsed.

I originally `visible-xs` class but I have a custom collapse point on my navbar so this doesn't hide the logo correctly.

Is there a way to show an image only when the `navbar` is collapsed?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-left"><img src="Images/Logo_small.gif"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: where's your navbar-brand? Anyway, just add visible-xs to it, it should work fine...

Comment: @Lee - like I said...I have a custom collapse point and thus I cannot just add `visible-xs` to it.  I am trying to find a way to only show my logo when the collapsed version of the navbar is applied.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a custom collapse point? Because I think using the default BS point will make it a lot easier, and I Think it works okay for most people.. just curious that's all.

Comment: I had to use a custom breakpoint because of the large number of menu options.  If I stayed with the default breakpoint then the menu options started wrapping and taking up multiple rows as I shrunk the screen down.  It looked horrible so I just added the breakpoint to switch to the collapsed view instead of wrapping.  I really wish that I didn't have to do that as I know my issue would be far easier without the custom breakpoint.

Answer (score -1):

**1st understanding:**
If you want that your logo disappear when the menu disappear and its hamburger version appear WITHOUT using BS default class `visible-xs` as you mention, you can add some css rule in css Media queries

```
@media (min-width: custom collapse point-min) and (max-width: custom collapse point-max) {
    .navbar-collapse {
        .logotohide { display: none; } // or opacity: 0 or whatever
    }
}
```

So, if the custom point are the same for the collasping and the logo hiding, this will do the job.

**2nd understanding:**
Normally your navbar will have a new class when you open it (with responsiv hamburger menu icon). Then you can simply use css to hide element of the navbar with this specific class.

for example :

```
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        .logotohide { display: none; } // or opacity: 0 or whatever
       // using LESS 
      &.in { .logotohide { display: block; } }
    }
   // without LESS
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        .logotohide { display: block; } // or opacity: 1 or whatever
    }
```

When your navbar will have a new class because of its collapsed status, the second css rule will take the power !

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer!  Forgive my lack of css experience...but it doesn't like the format of that `.logotohide` section within the navbar/navbar.collapse sections.  Am I just missing something simple?

Comment: Actually, I do not see a new class being applied to the navbar when it collapses.  I don't think that this approach will work.

Comment: Look harder... in parents divs for example. Or just use bootstrap how it should be used, I have done want you try to do many times. But not a reason to downvote when people try to helps you.

Comment: I was not the one that downvoted your answer, bro.  I agree that it was lame to do so.  Any chance that you could create a codepen or similar example of this?  I have looked all over (parents and all) and I do not see any classes changing.